# how to extract just the IP address from a DNS query

Tags: bash, dns, dig

On Alpine Linux, I'd like to know how to extract just the IP address from a DNS / dig query.  The query I'm running looks like this:

```
lab-1:/var/# dig +answer smtp.mydomain.net +short   
smtp.ggs.mydomain.net
10.11.11.11
```

I'd like to be able to get just the IP address returned.
I'm currently playing around with the bash pipe and the awk command.  But so far, nothing I've tried is working.

Thanks.

Comment: drop `+answer` use just `+short`

Comment: that doesn't work.  still gives me the same results @man0v

Comment: weird, it works for me on `centos`.. wonder what version of `dig` you are using? What distro(or os)?

Comment: i'm running alpine linux

Comment: @dot post dig version too. Use `dig -v`

Comment: Is smtp.mydomain.net an alias for smtp.ggs.mydomain.net?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I believe `dig +short` outputs two lines for you because the domain
you query, `smtp.mydomain.net` is a CNAME for `smtp.ggs.mydomain.net`,
and dig prints the intermediate resolution step.

You can probably rely on the last line from dig's output being the IP
you want, though, and therefore the following should do:

```
dig +short smtp.mydomain.net | tail -n1
```

Comment: What if it returns 2 IPs (2 A records)?

Answer (score 8):

@dhag's answer sounds good; if you do not want to “rely on the last line from dig's output being the IP” you can use `grep` to extract just the numerical IP address:

```
dig +short smtp.mydomain.net | grep '^[.0-9]*$'
```

Comment: @JordanBrough No, it doesn't